# Perl mongodb remove record question

Tags: perl, mongodb

use the following code, delete the specified document.

```
sub delete_post{
my $post_id = shift;
my $post_to_delete = $posts->find_one({"_id" => $conn->oid($post_id)})->{_id};
$posts->remove({"_id" => $post_to_delete});
```

}

if use this code:

```
sub delete_post{
my $post_id = shift;
$posts->remove({"_id" => $conn->oid($post_id)});
```

}

remove all documents.

Does mongodb cannot accept the oid as criteria to delete document?

Comment: Why do you need `$conn->oid`? Does the following not work? `$posts->remove({"_id" => $post_id});`

Comment: Disaster. The first method, randomly remove one documents or remove all documents. The second method, remove none.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480645/pel-mongo-coll-find-one-id-xxxx-method-not-function-as-expected) is another question about unsecure use _id as key in find method.

Answer (score 2):

Use the MongoDB::OID method to create _id object instead of $conn->oid;

```
sub delete_post{
my $post_id = shift;
my $oid = MongoDB::OID->new(value => $post_id);
$posts->remove({"_id" => $oid});
$db->log->insert({"removed_post" => $post_id});
```

}