# Perl mongo $coll->find_one({"_id" => "xxxx"}) method not function as expected

Tags: perl, mongodb

I know another users had asked this question. I test and it doesn't work. I find this problem when use the $coll->remove({"_id" => "xxxx"}) not hehaviour as expected.

Following is the summary of my test:

```
print Dumper $db->posts->find_one({"_id" => "4d92740b2239007c16130000"});
```

$VAR1= undef;

```
print Dumper $db->posts->find_one({"_id" => $conn->oid("4d92740b2239007c16130000")});
```

print out a document with _id => "4d9274032e62007c16110000"

Does the autogenerated _id object can be used to manage documents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl mongodb remove record question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475636/perl-mongodb-remove-record-question)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. If your previous question isn't getting answered, edit it to be more specific or descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Removing

```
db.things.remove({_id: myobject._id});
```

The `_id` is *not* a string. It's a 12 byte binary value stored as a BSON object:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

You can remove by the `_id` but you can't use the 24 digit hex string representation. This is exactly the same behavior as `find_one()` which you have already discovered.

```
$coll->remove({"_id" => $myObject->{_id}});
```

Comment: the problem is can't find myobject by _id. Should you explain how to use a id string to find myobject?

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear distinction between an objectid and its string representation. Why should the first find_one() with the string representation return a result if you are actually using an ObjectId as _id here? So the behavior is completely correct - independent of the driver used. If you introduce your string object ids for whatever reason then you will be able to search by string. As long as the driver injects decicated objectid (which aren't strings) you will have to search by them and not by their string representation.